# getString doesn't return the good string in hebrew on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources

I'm localizing my app in hebrew and it works when I define it `@string/invoicenodata` but when I use `getString`, it return the default resource (english) and not the hebrew translation.

I set the accurate value in the folders : `/values-he and /values-iw (in strings.xml)`.

Btw it works in french or german.

My class extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Any clue ?

Comment: you may need to download some libraries to support hebrew and other languages

Comment: i don't think so. when i use the syntax @string/.. it works. it's only the getString which doesn't work

Comment: try calling `getResources().getString()`

Comment: my bad, the resource was in strings-he and not in strings-iw. sorry to bother you